# Trigger a jQuery function before all the clicks get executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, order-of-execution

I was trying to implement a permission check on my application as follows. If the user clicked on an element with a specific attribute `check-permission`, execute a jquery function and check for permission.

The real issue i am facing is there may be more than 20 clickable elements in my application where permission check is enabled. These elements can be `div` or `a` tag etc and are attached to some other jquery events; for example; trigger a popup modal, redirect to a page etc.

I want to execute my `permissionCheck` function before all other click events get executed. I created a custom event and bind this to the click function; but this is not working.

Can someone suggest me a good method to implement this ? Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: `.trigger(eventName);` when binding event

Comment: How does the permission check function work? Are you saying that if the user clicks multiple times the second and subsequent clicks can occur before the first permission check is complete (because it does something asynchronous, like make an ajax request)? Please [edit]  your question to add the relevant code.

Comment: Checking permissions on client side is not a good solution because client computer/user has complete access over it. They can alter the attributes with inspection tools. so if a user changed the attribute `check-permission`  then the functionality will not work.

Comment: on document ready,check if user has not permission then unbind all click events

Comment: Tried using `event.preventDefault()` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this - `stopImmediatePropagation`; getting all events using `jQuery._data(this, 'events')` and wrapping it with your validation function; unbinding events and binding them back.

However, in my opinion, the most convenient and proper way is to create custom events like `permitted` and `unpermitted`, and attach to it instead of `click`. In that way, you will be able to have both permission-aware and simple handlers. Also, the code will become more readable, because you will see which methods require permission.

```
$("selector")
    .on('permitted', function() {
        // executed if permission check passed            
    })
    .on('unpermitted', function() {
        // executed if permission check failed    
    })
    .on('click', function() {
        // executed always!
    });
```

You can dispatch these events in your `click` handler,

```
$(document).on('click', '[check-permission]', function(e) {
    var checkResult; 
    // custom permission validation logic

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(checkResult ? 'permitted' : 'unpermitted'));

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Attach all actions which require these permissions to `permitted` and it will work.

Here is the **[working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5h2vs12g/4/)**. In this example, `decrease` and `increase` buttons change the size of these links if `permit` checkbox is checked. Otherwise, it shows an error.

However, implementing a permission validation at client-side should only be used in decorative purposes. You shouldn't rely on this. A proper, secure and non-compromisable authorization should be implemented at the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

your answer is stopImmediatePropagation which stops bubbling like stopPropagation and prevents all other handlers execute.

Here is an example.

```
<div id="testFalse" data-check-permission="false">Test False</div>
<div id="testTrue" data-check-permission="true">Test True</div>



$('[data-check-permission="true"],[data-check-permission="false"]').on('click', function (event) {
    var $eventTarget = $(event.currentTarget);
    if ($eventTarget.data("check-permission") == false) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});


$("#testFalse,#testTrue").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: Note that this `data-check-permission` click handler should be declared **first** as it provides [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) event execution order.